# How to find all keys with certain name in json?

Tags: python, json

I have many similar JSON objects with different sizes, I need to run through all keys with certain names and get values of it.

for example I have 3 JSONs:

```
[
  {
    "name": "temp",
    "url": "http://temp.com",
    "content": {
      "content": "temp",
      "url": "https://temp1.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "temp",
    "url": "http://temp.com",
    "content": [
      {
        "content": "temp"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://temp1.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "temp",
    "content": {
      "content": "temp"
    }
  }
]
```

So I need extract the value from all keys "`url`" (but this key is not necessary and can be not in json )

the target output:

```
http://temp.com
https://temp1.com
http://temp.com
https://temp1.com
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippet of what you tried?

Comment: Your jsons doesn't seem legit as they are missing commas.

Comment: repaired json, I've tried to get all keys by bracket notation, but in cause of it all have different sizes I have some issues @KaranNagpal Im looking for any universal find way

Comment: load it using module `json` and you will have normal list with dictionares and you can use `.keys()` to get keys. And you will need recursion to get keys from nested dictionares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it using module `json` and you will have normal `list` with `dictionares` and you can use `.keys()` to get all keys and check if there is `'url'`.

And you need recursion to get `keys` from nested `lists`/`dictionares`.

---

Minimal working code with your example data

```
text = '''[
  {
    "name": "temp",
    "url": "http://temp.com",
    "content": {
      "content": "temp",
      "url": "https://temp1.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "temp",
    "url": "http://temp.com",
    "content": [
      {
        "content": "temp"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://temp1.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "temp",
    "content": {
      "content": "temp"
    }
  }
]'''
        
import json

def get_url(data, key):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        # check nested elements
        for item in data:
            yield from get_url(item, key)

    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        # check key in dictionary
        if key in data.keys():
            #print(data[key])
            yield data[key]

        # check nested elements
        for item in data.values():
            yield from get_url(item, key)

# --- main ---

#with open('data.json') as fh:
#    data = json.load(fh)

data = json.loads(text)

results = list(get_url(data, 'url'))

print(results)
```

Result:

```
['http://temp.com', 'https://temp1.com', 'http://temp.com', 'https://temp1.com']
```

---

If you want to get also `path` to element

```
def get_url(data, key, path=''):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for number, item in enumerate(data):
            yield from get_url(item, key, f'{path}[{number}]')
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        if key in data.keys():
            #print(data[key])
            yield (data[key], f'{path}["{key}"]')
        for name, item in data.items():
            yield from get_url(item, key, f'{path}["{name}"]')
```

Result:

```
[
   ('http://temp.com', '[0]["url"]'), 
   ('https://temp1.com', '[0]["content"]["url"]'), 
   ('http://temp.com', '[1]["url"]'), 
   ('https://temp1.com', '[1]["content"][1]["url"]')
]
```

Comment: I added version which gives also path to element

Answer (score 1):

I think a recursive generator is probably the way to go about this:

```py
def iter_values(key, list_or_dict):
    if isinstance(list_or_dict, list):
        # we're inside a list now, so yield from each element
        for obj in list_or_dict:
            if isinstance(obj, (list, dict)):
                yield from iter_values(key, obj)
    
    # we're dealing with a dict,
    # so check if it has the key and if so,
    # yield it
    if key in list_or_dict:
        yield list_or_dict[key]

    # it's possible there is a nested object in a different key
    # (e.g. your "content" which has a "url"),
    # so iterate over those as well
    for k, v in list_or_dict.items():
        if k != key and isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
            yield from iter_values(v)
```

If you don't know how generators work, you can turn it into a list by doing

```py
list(iter_values("url", data))
```